# Synchronize my local database with online server database for Comparison

Tags: php, sql, database

i have online db and Loacal db

i want way Secure when the user enter value Compar it with the local db if it If it exists or not ?

the online db phpymadmin with web php

the local db my sql..?

Comment: your question needs more details, where are both databses ? how the check could be done with your local db?

Comment: first db in onlinehost (hostinger) second db local im my room with server

Comment: Ok so you want, for any action done remotely by users in your remote db, a similar one for your local db? did I get it right?

Comment: Like, if user enter number  in the field,,, This field will compare with the local database, not online db .. If the number is present .. complete the process .. if it is not present, the user cannot be complted

Comment: Still ambiguous unless you give us some code examples and we can go from there.